# how to install erratic-robot on the hydro?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone
I want to migrate fuerte package to hydro. Before the package depend on erratic robot package. How can i install erratic-robot on hydro?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198778/how-to-install--erratic-robot--on-the-hydro?/) by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2014-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the erratic_robot package is still a rosbuild package, and isn't released into Hydro.

You can install it from source in a rosbuild workspace, but it can't be released until it's converted to catkin.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on 2014-12-02**:
Thank you.
I downloaded the erratic_robot-master.zip  and make it, and then use catkin_make command, but package player(erratic robot) still can not be found. how can i converted it to catkin?
I already installed it in fuerte, now i have two version in my computer

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-02**:
since erratic_robot is a rosbuild package, you cannot build it with catkin_make, and you cannot build against it from a catkin package. You should set up a separate rosbuild workspace for Hydro, overlaid on your Hydro catkin workspace, and built it there.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-02**:
See http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin#rosbuild_workspace_on_top_of_catkin_workspace for instructions on how to set up a rosbuild workspace that is overlaid on your catkin workspace.

**Comment by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on 2014-12-02**:
Thank you very much , now i will try to do what you have suggested.

**Comment by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on 2014-12-03**:
Thank you very much, it worked.